# kafka mirrormaker only build topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I run the command:

`"JAVA_HOME=./jdk ./origin/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --whitelist ".*" --consumer.config config/consumer_mirror.properties --producer.config config/producer_mirror.properties"`

to make a mirror, however it only copy the topics name, no data copied

the consumer property file content is

```
zookeeper.connect=10.40.80.61:2181

# timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=1000000

#consumer group id
group.id=mirror-maker-group1

#consumer timeout
#consumer.timeout.ms=5000

mirror.topics.whitelist=*
client.id=mirror_maker_consumer1
```

the producer property file content is

```
metadata.broker.list=localhost:9092

# name of the partitioner class for partitioning events; default partition spreads data randomly
#partitioner.class=

# specifies whether the messages are sent asynchronously (async) or synchronously (sync)
producer.type=async

# specify the compression codec for all data generated: none , gzip, snappy.
# the old config values work as well: 0, 1, 2 for none, gzip, snappy, respectivally
compression.codec=none

# message encoder
serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder
client.id=mirror_maker_producer
```

Comment: Please show both property files

Comment: Also, as documented in the MirrorMaker section, you should create the topic yourself rather than let the defaults be applied for you

Comment: zookeeper.connect=10.40.80.61:2181

# timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=1000000

#consumer group id
group.id=mirror-maker-group1

#consumer timeout
#consumer.timeout.ms=5000

mirror.topics.whitelist=*
client.id=mirror_maker_consumer1

Comment: Please [edit] the question itself

Comment: You should be using `bootstrap.server` if you have Kafka 0.10 or higher, not `zookeeper.connect`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I work with Kafka 0.8.1

Comment: I have no experience with such an old version, but I do think that mirrormaker defaults to read the latest offsets, so are there messages actively being produced or have you tried changing the offset start position?

Comment: I changed the parameter auto.offset.reset to "smallest", but it didn't work